# IF statement in WHERE clause with Oracle SQL on count

Tags: sql, if-statement, count, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I am trying to develop a PUT method for a website. I am using the following code to make sure the information the user is entering is different from what we already have before making changes to the database (also to prevent a whole bunch of log files in case the user hits submit too many times):

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM iam.credential
    WHERE iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE = :1
    AND iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_NAME   = :2
    AND iam.credential.LOST_OR_STOLEN    = :3 
    AND iam.credential.STATUS            = :4
    AND iam.credential.EXPIRATION_DATE   = :5
    AND iam.credential.ISSUING_LOCATION  = :6 
    AND iam.credential.PHYSICAL_FORM     = :7 
    AND iam.credential.ASSOCIATED_DEVICE = :8
    AND iam.credential.DISPLAY_NAME      = :9;
```

I am grabbing the values from my webpage, but I am running into issues when the value is NULL. I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM iam.credential
    WHERE 
    IF iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE is not null THEN
        iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE = :1
    ELSE
        iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE is null
    END IF
    AND 
    IF iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_NAME is not null THEN
       iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_NAME    = :2
    ELSE
       iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_NAME    is null
    END IF
    //and so on
```

I can't use

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM iam.credential
    WHERE (iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE = :1
    OR iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE is null)
```

because that will return a count of 2 when I only want the one that matches what the user input.

Basically I want the count to either return a 1 or a 0 for if the record exists or if it doesn't.

I want the WHERE clause to be dynamically changed based on what the user provides.

If the user doesn't provide a value because it is not required it will be null. I need query to change to

```
    credential_name is null
```

because

```
    credential_name = null
```

doesn't work in oracle.

if it is not null then I need it to be

```
   credential_name = :1
```

and it will be filled with the value that the user provided.

```
   credential_name is :1
```

doesn't work in oracle either.

I will get two records back if I have two credentials of the same type but one record has a (null) value for CREDENTIAL_NAME and the other has 'DaisyDuck'.

Comment: What should happen if the table value is null and the user-supplied value is not null, and vice versa? Should those be counted or not? And how/why does your second query get a count of two - are you sure it's counting the same row twice, not getting partial matches on two similar rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just want to check that both the column value and the supplied value are null, or the column and the supplied value match:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM iam.credential
WHERE (iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE = :1
OR (iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_TYPE is null AND :1 is null))
AND (iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_NAME = :2
OR (iam.credential.CREDENTIAL_NAME is null AND :2 is null))
AND ...
```

You may not have to do that for every value if you have table columns that are not nullable and you're checking that the matching user-supplied value is not null before you reach this point.

Your approach has a potential flaw though. In a multi-user system two sessions could enter the same values, both check and get a count of zero, and both then insert - causing a duplicate row unless you also have a unique constraint across all the values. If you do have such a constraint then the count will prevent a violation on insert some of the time, but not always, so may not be worth the extra trip to the database.

Comment: First I am checking to see if the record exists using the unique key before adding. If it doesn't exist then I insert.

This count is to see if anything is different that merits an update to the database. If it does exist and it is different then I update